# How do I get a Java Servlet Container to save files as an "owner / group" other than Tomcat?

Tags: linux, file, tomcat, permissions, io

I have a java servlet. When it saves files, it saves them as tomcat:tomcat (in a linux environment). I actually need it to save it as sportsfan:tomcat as sportsfan is the FTP user and also needs access to create, modify or overwrite these files.

I thought about running tomcat as sportsfan:tomcat, but I'm running multiple applications under the one tomcat instance.

Perhaps the best way to do this would be to have the FTP user log in as part of the tomcat group. Would that be a correct way?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Adding your `sportsfan` user ftp to the `tomcat` group could be a good solution but before that check which are the modifiable files in you system with this permission and consider the security risks.

Another solution: Create a `sportsfan` group and add your `sportsfan` user to it. Then change the group of your `upload` directory and set it as `setgid`:

```
chgrp sportsfan upload
chmod g+s upload
```

After that the new files in the `upload` will be created with `tomcat:sportsfan` owner:group. It's not exactly what you asked for but changing the user id (setuid directories) is not supported on Linux. Wikipedia has a pretty good article about [setuid and setgid directories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#setuid_and_setgid_on_directories). Futhermore, you have to set the `umask` value of the `tomcat` user to *000x* (e.g. 0002) or a similar value which gives full access to the group.

3rd solution: set up a cron job which changes the permission in every n minutes.

Comment: Very interested in your solution regarding a sportsfan group and user but I didn't quite understand it.